# Why does MongoDB keep crashing?

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB 4.4.1 replica set, running on Ubuntu 20.04 with all the default (proper) ulimits set.  Permissions on the data directory are also proper.  It crashes about once a day under load.

The error message in the log doesn't immediately explain the issue.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-05T22:25:46.854+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23083,   "ctx":"conn503635","msg":"Invariant failure","attr":{"expr":"ret","error":"UnknownError: -31803: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found","file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":1600}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-10-05T22:25:46.856+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23084,   "ctx":"conn503635","msg":"\n\n***aborting after invariant() failure\n\n"}
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going wrong or how to fix it?

Comment: Filesystem corruption? Backup & restore the deployment.

Comment: We recently started seeing this as well. Did you ever solve this problem?